# Detecting white blobs on grayscale image using MSER in opencv

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, mser

I have images which are largely black with few whitish blobs on them.
I want to distinguish such images from those which do not have such blobs.

I tried MSER and tuned its parameters to correctly detect blobs in most of the images which have them and return 0 result in those that don't.

Here's my MSER parameter configuration.

```
mser = cv2.MSER_create(_delta = 3,_min_diversity=0.2,_edge_blur_size = 5 ,_max_variation = 0.10,_min_area = 120,_max_area = 1000)
```

Below is a test image:

[image: test image]

The white region on the top is not being detected.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using MSER, here are two simpler approaches

#### Method #1

Convert image to grayscale and Otsu's threshold to obtain a binary image. Then find contours and filter using a minimum threshold area. Depending on how much white blob you want to detect, you can adjust this threshold area. Here's the results with the detected white region highlighted in green

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]

cnts = cv2.findContours(thresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]
for c in cnts:
    area = cv2.contourArea(c)
    if area > 50:
        cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), -1)

cv2.imshow('thresh', thresh)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.imwrite('original.png', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

#### Method #2

Since OpenCV images are stored as Numpy arrays, we can simply use slicing to create a mask of pixels greater than some threshold. Here's the results

[image]

```
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
mask = (image >= [150.,150.,150.]).all(axis=2)
image[mask] = [36, 255, 12]

cv2.imshow('image', image)
cv2.waitKey()
```